# Squirrel SQL Client do not dosplay contents of table

Tags: sql, squirrel-sql

I have set up SQuirrel SQL Client version 3.7 on my windows machine to connect to progress database which is running on Unix server. I am able to connect with the database and view the tables. The issue is that I am not able to see the contents of the table with special character in table name like "abc-def".I am able to see the contents of tables where this special character "-" is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would avoid characters like this in a table name as it's more hassle than it's worth.

However, if you must then you'll need to surround the table name with quotes. e.g.

```
select * from "abc-def"
```

Surrounding with quotes will also be case sensitive so make sure you have the right case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree with your suggestion not to use special character but we already have huge database were such tables exists.To see contents of the table, I am using query like select * from pub.\"abc-def\" (which display all the data) but don't know how to configure this in squirrel client tool.